# animate div color plus hover animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a line created out of a div now what i am trying to do is animate the div color, background grey, then it fills white, then the white fills back to grey like its sliding through. then on hover the line and text slide up about 10px, then when release it goes back to default position.

like this one here at the bottom [example](https://www.ankoku-toshi-jutsu.com/#product)

```css
.scroll-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 340;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 4.16667%;
    height: 6.66667%;
    min-height: 60px;
    font-family: 'rajdhani', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.scroll-indicator .border-grey {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333;
}
.scroll-indicator .border {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 200;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
}
.scroll-indicator em {
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    transform-origin: center center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 12px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.scroll-indicator {
    bottom: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="scroll-indicator" style="opacity: 1; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
  <div class="border-grey"></div>
  <div class="border" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); transform-origin: 0% 0% 0px;"></div>
  <em>scroll</em>
 </a>
```

Comment: Can you please include a link to a JSFiddle so it can be properly tested and experimented with? Additionally, it's unclear from this question what your problem is. S/O is not a place to ask for work to be done, but rather to answer a specific problem you face. Please detail what you've been able to accomplish, what you've tried, what worked, what didn't, etc.

Comment: the above code snippet works fine just no line animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of CSS3 [`animations`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) and [`transitions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) to implement that behaviour.

To implement an animation it's usually good to understand what is happening before trying to code it. In this case we can describe it in 3 easy steps:

1. element starts in `top: 0` with `height: 0`
2. element stay in `top: 0` with `height: 100%`
3. element moves to `top: 100%` with `height: 0`

With that in mind we can just code our [`keyframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

Following is a small example on how to do it:

```css
body {
  background: #555;
}

.scroll-indicator {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 30px;
 left: 50%;
 height: 60px;
 transition: height .25s linear;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.scroll-indicator:hover {
 height: 75px;
}

.scroll-indicator .border-grey {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 2px;
 background: #333;
}

.scroll-indicator .border-white {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 2px;
 background: #fff;
 animation-name: animation;
    animation-duration: 3s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.scroll-indicator span {
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

@keyframes animation {
 0% {
  height: 0;
 }
 33% {
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
 }
 66% {
  top: 100%;
  height: 0;
 }
 100% {}
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-indicator">
 <div class="border-grey"></div>
 <div class="border-white"></div>
 <span>scroll</span>
</div>
```

Comment: it jumps up and down when clicked any way to prevent that?

Comment: What browser are you using? I could notice that behaviour in Chrome 63 indeed, but it's alright in Firefox and Edge. I would guess that it's a small issue with Chrome. Click is making the element lose it's hover behaviour somehow.